# Python Tensor Flow issue with fitting line to data

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I've recently been trying to implement tensor flow into my projects, and I attempted to use the [Basic Regression Using Keras Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) for regression. However, I am having issues with fitting the line onto the data: [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMlU6.png) & [prediction vs. data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIHeT.png). I've normalized my data, ran it through 1000 epochs, and the data seems fine. Here is the data and the code I've used. Does anyone know why the prediction is so different from the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_uEr28c_y9Nfnu3BH_RT5RLpfi1Nr2ePBaO_RLexdU4/edit?usp=sharing)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Make NumPy printouts easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

print(tf.__version__)
train_dataset = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state = 0)
test_dataset = df.drop(train_dataset.index)
train_dataset.describe().transpose()
train_features = train_dataset.copy()
test_features = test_dataset.copy()

train_labels = train_features.pop('Max')
test_labels = test_features.pop('Max')
train_dataset.describe().transpose()[['mean','std']]
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(np.array(train_features))
print(normalizer.mean.numpy())
first = np.array(train_features[:1])

with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
  print('First example:', first)
  print()
  print('Normalized:', normalizer(first).numpy())
date = np.array(train_features['Date Lifted'])

date_normalizer = layers.Normalization(input_shape=[1,], axis=None)
date_normalizer.adapt(date)
date_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    date_normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])

date_model.summary()
date_model.predict(date[:10])
date_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss='mean_absolute_error')
%%time
history = date_model.fit(
    train_features['Date Lifted'],
    train_labels,
    epochs=100,
    # Suppress logging.
    verbose=0,
    # Calculate validation results on 20% of the training data.
    validation_split = 0.2)
hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
hist.tail()
def plot_loss(history):
  plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
  plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')
  plt.ylim([0, 1000])
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Error [Max]')
  plt.legend()
  plt.grid(True)
plot_loss(history)
test_results = {}

test_results['date_model'] = date_model.evaluate(
    test_features['Date Lifted'],
    test_labels, verbose=0)
x = tf.linspace(0, 250, 251)
y = date_model.predict(x)
def plot_horsepower(x, y):
  plt.scatter(train_features['Date Lifted'], train_labels, label='Data')
  plt.plot(x, y, color='k', label='Predictions')
  plt.xlabel('Date Lifted')
  plt.ylabel('Max')
  plt.legend()
plot_horsepower(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model only has a single neuron?

I imagine you'll see better results if you use a more complicated model, with more layers and more units per layer.

Comment: I'm just using the basic template provided by that tutorial, but I would love to know how to use more layers and neurons. My data is limited, but I was hoping i could train it on around 50 data points.

Comment: try setting `layers.Dense(units=1)`

to something like `layers.Dense(units = 10), layers.Dense(units = 1)`.

This should still give you a linear prediction (Dense layers have linear activation by default), but with hopefully better accuracy.

Comment: Adding more neurons didn't help it, and the model became more inaccurate.
[graph](https://imgur.com/gallery/2pKHde4)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).